# Compute complementary CDF given a list of coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, networkx

I have a list of clustering coefficients for nodes in a graph, that I obtained from NetworkX:

```
coefficients = nx.clustering(G)
```

Now I would like to plot the complementary CDF of these coefficients, so that on the X-axis I have the coefficient value `x`, and on the Y-axis the fraction of nodes which clustering coefficient is greater than or equal to x, i.e. `P(X >= x)`.

How can I do this in Python? Should I be using `scipy.stats.rv_discrete.cdf`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.cdf.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scipy.stats.rv_discrete.cdf` seems overkill. Just sorting the list of coefficients and plotting them versus the range `[1,0]` should give the desired complementary CDF.

Here is some example code, showing the complementary CDF for different random graphs:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

for edges in range(200, 2001, 200):
    G = nx.gnm_random_graph(100, edges)
    coefficients = nx.clustering(G)
    x = np.concatenate([[0], np.sort(list(coefficients.values())), [1]])
    plt.plot(x, np.linspace(1, 0, len(x)), label=f'100 nodes, {edges} edges')
plt.xlabel('Clustering coefficient')
plt.ylabel('P(X ≥ x)')
plt.margins(x=0.02)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.legend(title='Random graphs')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

With `np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))` you'd get `P(X ≤ x)`.

Comment: I believe for C-CDF the y-axis should be `P(X > x)` and for CDF, it should be `P(X ≤ x)` instead.